# Remove Foreign Key Relationships From All Tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a database that has several tables.  Many of the tables have fields with foreign key constraints.  I want to truncate the tables and then repopulate them with new data, and I also want to take off the foreign keys, as some of the relationships have changed.  basically, I want to build the FK constraints up from scratch again.  How can I remove the current FK constraints from all tables?

Comment: You could use `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` to disable foreign key constraints temporarily.

Comment: @Kerrek, this is the very reason I refrained from using foreign keys :-) JUst bullshit and not much added value... just my opinion.

Comment: @Tomas: well, that's debatable... foreign keys force you to *think* about your data model, I suppose. Disabling the checks is really just a maintenance operation that you should never do on a live database.

Comment: @Tomas: You got to be kidding. `FKs=Bullshit`, really? One of the benefits of relational databases is constraints enforcement.

Comment: @ypercube: I started with FK, but got many error messages during MTCE,loading data etc., so I removed them and got used to assure the integrity wo/FK.

Comment: @Tomas: I know there are certain operations than need special care when foreign keys exist (or temporarily setting them off). How can you assure data integrity without them though?

Comment: @ypercube: 1) I'm the only one who designs queries ;-) 2) I use transactions for every operation which requires more than 1 query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can play with the information_schema.
Take a look at this page

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html

```
select concat('alter table ',table_name,' drop foreign key ',constraint_name,';') 
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where constraint_schema = 'your_db' and referenced_table_name = 'table_name';
```

then run the output generated.

You can do something similar in order to truncate all tables.

```
select concat('truncate ',table_name,';') 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_db' and table_type = 'base table'
```

this one will truncate all tables within the specified database. So use it with care.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, too, but I didn't know the exact solution for MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

I"m guessing you already found a solution, since this post is six months old, but I recently had to come up with a script to drop foreign key constraints to a particular table in MySQL, so that may help anyone else in the same boat:

```
# create a handy dandy stored procedure
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DropConstraints(refschema VARCHAR(64), reftable VARCHAR(64), refcolumn VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    WHILE EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
        WHERE 1
        AND REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = refschema
        AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = reftable
        AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = refcolumn
    ) DO
        BEGIN
            SET @sqlstmt = (
                SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,' DROP FOREIGN KEY ',CONSTRAINT_NAME)
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
                WHERE 1
                AND REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = refschema
                AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = reftable
                AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = refcolumn
                LIMIT 1
            );
            PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sqlstmt;
            EXECUTE stmt1;
        END;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To run it, simply use:

```
SET @schema = 'schema_name';
CALL DropConstraints(@schema, 'TableName', 'Referenced_Column_1');
CALL DropConstraints(@schema, 'TableName', 'Referenced_Column_2');
```

And if you don't want to keep the procedure around:

```
DROP PROCEDURE DropConstraints;
```

Of course if you want to drop all FK constraints to the table, you can remove the refcolumn parameter and the last line of each where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol;
```

Comment: But I don't want to do that for every single table withing the database.  Is there any way to do this on a DB level?