# Error Code: 1022. Can't write; duplicate key in table - Change a lot of constraint names

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to update some of the table in my database, however I am getting this error. I searched here and found some answers saying that the problem is because I have other constraints with the same name. And that is right because if I change the name of the constraint it works. However, this update file is very long and I cannot alter all the constraints name one by one. What should I do?

When I put this code, for example, it gives the error

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `apscatalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;

CREATE TABLE `apscatalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `attribute_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Attribute ID',
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Value',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_MEDIA_GALLERY_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_MEDIA_GALLERY_ENTITY_ID` (`entity_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `apseav_attribute` (`attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `apscatalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Media Gallery Attribute Backend Table';
```

Comment: With _update file_ do you mean it's a DB dump or is it just a set of values that are loaded into the tables after being processed by a program? Could you possibly add a bit more clarity to the question - for instance: one of your table definitions, its constraints and data which results in that error when being attempted to load? With the given information, it's not very intuitive to figure out what might actually be happening there.

Comment: it's a dump actually.. I edited the question to explain better

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm able to create the table successfully with that. Although the two tables referenced were added with their supposed `PRIMARY KEYS` that weren't shown in the schema above. See [this](http://rextester.com/NHIZX62234) demo. If you're able to create the tables then, of course, the data would need to be checked. However, I'm a bit puzzled. If it's a DB dump, and it came from a legit source, then it really shouldn't cause any problems as long as it's complete and imported in totality. Have you also tried loading this dump by creating a new database first?

Comment: yes, I created a new database and runned this sql and it worked. However, I need to execute it in the database that I am using (that already have much content). I know the problem is because I am using constraint names that already exists, but i don't know how to solve it without renaming them one by one

Comment: If you want to incrementally add the data from somewhere else to what you already have, then I reckon the problem isn't in the name of the constraints, but possibly with how those constraints are designed. It may be that foreign key relationships you're following is different from the foreign key relationships in the dump. However, one of the ways could be to [remove all the constraints from your DB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7047624/2298301) first and then add every constraint from the dump again, so that both the schemas become consistent. Please only try this on a backup copy first though!

Comment: I think the problem really is the constraints because when I delete one constraint and run the create code that will create that constraint again (like the one above) it works. however, if i do not delete it first or put a different name on the new one, it gives me the error

Comment: I tried to do that but it didn't work also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141915/discussion-between-dhruv-saxena-and-rayane-de-araujo).